# LDAP and database synchronization

Tags: database, ldap, openldap

I have issue where I need store info about users in DB and authorize via LDAP.

A bit more detailed.

1. I have two depends system which has common for users (approach something like "stackoverflow" where you can create login based on google account..).
2. Not all users can have access. For example, have company which have contact persons and some of them have access to developed system. That is mean persons have foring key to company and some of them must have records in LDAP.

I'm new in LDAP. Please suggest architecture solution for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding LDAP to database synchronization, you could create a routine for exporting LDAP objects into a .csv file and then importing it's records to the database.

You could, for example, use LDAP's user "uid" attribute to indicate an object's uniquiness on the database.

Also, there's [JDBC-LDAP Bridge Driver](http://www.openldap.org/jdbcldap/), that you can use to develop Java applications that can access data stored in a directory server.